# my ajax results are attached to html then disappears

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function login(id){

var dataString = 'Id='+ id;

$("#infos").show();
$("#infos").fadeIn(900).html('Please wait... <img     src="dashboard/images/loading.gif" />');
        alert(id);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax-login.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        $("#infos").hide();             
alert(data);
        $('#info').html(data);
        $("#info").show();          
    }
});
 }
</script>
<p class="help-block redtext"  id="infos" ></p> 
<div id="info"></div>
```

Above is my code and apparently when i attach the results to the div with id='info', they stay there for like 2 seconds then they disappear, the php script that loads data loads very well and it actually shows but it doesnt stay, it gets lost after 1 or 2 seconds, please help

Comment: Does this alert "alert(data);" happen more then once? In other words, are you calling login(id) more then once?

Comment: What calls this function?